# what's the different between the following two mysql statement? (group-wise maximum of a certain column from mysql document)

Tags: mysql, sql

what's the different between the following two mysql statement?

```
select article, dealer, price from shop s1 where price=(select max(**s2.price**) from shop s2
                                                        where s1.article = s2.article)
                                           order by article;
```

```
select article, dealer, price from shop s1 where price=(select max(**s1.price**) from shop s2
                                                        where s1.article = s2.article)
                                           order by article;
```

The query result of these two are different, I just cannot understand the different of these two. Please help me to understand it, thanks very much.

Comment: The first one has max(s2.price) and second one has max(s1.price)?

Comment: Can you plz elaborate your prblem wht u r not getting in  the above query.

Comment: max(s1.price) is just the price from the main query or put another way the subquery cannot work  a max(s1.price) from a table that is not invoked in the sub query query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is a correlated subquery, but the returned value is the same `s1.price` as in the outer query.  Because the table used for the inner query and outer query are the same, it is functionally equivalent to:

```
where price is not null and article is not null
```

That is, any valid article with a valid price is going to match the result from the subquery.

The first one is a correlated subquery that gets the maximum price for each article and then returns the outer rows.  With the right indexes, this is usually the most efficient way to write such a query.

Comment: does the main query is the outer side query and the sub query is the inner query,
just like the outer side for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) and the inner side for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)?

Comment: @JYP2011 . . . You can think of subqueries in this context as being logically equivalent to nested loops.  The effects are the same, but that might not be how they are actually implemented.

Comment: okay, and can you briefly describe the actually implementation? It will help me to understand the principle of this kind of query in sql. thank you:-) @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @JYP2011 . . . This is no "actual implementation".  Databases have a wide variety of algorithms available in their underlying engines.